# JHipster Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component

Tags: jhipster

I am trying to deploy JHipster to Tomcat 9 (java 8). It is fine when I deploy it locally, but it gives an error upon loading to Linux VM:

```
FAIL - Application at context path [/web-app-0.0.4-SNAPSHOT] could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/web-app-0.0.4-SNAPSHOT]]]
```

[Web app image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icrdx.png)

Upon inspecting catalina.out on Tomcat I see that:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - Failed to create parent directories for [/target/webApp.log]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - openFile(target/webApp.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: target/webApp.log (No such file or directory)
```

This probably means that I don't have privileges to write this file? Where should I add privileges to fix it?

**How could I disable this logging alltogether? I suspect application.yml file has something to do with it.**

EDIT 1:
It is possible to start the application when adding target folder to root and creating webApp.log file to it. Because I followed [DigitalOceans](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/install-tomcat-9-ubuntu-1804) guide, I also made tomcat user the owner of the folder:

```
sudo chown -R tomcat /target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `logging` key/value in `application.yml` to disable the logging a file.  This was removed after discussion in [this issue](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/8582).  This change which will be included in JHipster v5.4.3+

Comment: I was expecting the same when deleting the key/value right now. Good that they are going to make this intuitive fix in the future.